# C# Task Error Not all code returns path

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I`m getting the error: "not all paths return value" for the following function

```
public Computer[] FetchComputers()
        {
            Task<Computer[]> T1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return computerRepo.GetComputers();
            });

            T1.ContinueWith(c=>
            {
                return c.Result;
            });
        }
```

I can do:

```
public Computer[] FetchComputers()
        {
            Task<Computer[]> T1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return computerRepo.GetComputers();
            });

            return T1.Result;
        }
```

But the problem with this is when the method "computerRepo.GetComputers()" takes to long my MainThread is blocked and UI freezes.

How can I execute this Task without blocking the UI using Task?

**UPDATE:**

```
public Computer[] GetComputers()
        {
            Task<Computer[]> T1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int x;
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
                {
                    x = i;
                }
                var computer = new Computer[]
                {
                new Computer() { Name = "srv01", IPAddress = "10.17.138.169" },
                new Computer() { Name = "srv02", IPAddress = "10.17.136.25" },
                new Computer() { Name = "srv03", IPAddress = "10.167.9.22" }
                };
                return computer;
            });

            return T1.Result;
        }
```

How to implement async here?

```
public async Task<Computer[]> FetchComputers()
        {
            return computerRepo.GetComputers();
        }
```

IS THIS POSSIBLE?

Comment: You will need `Task<Computer[]> FetchComputers()` and probably with `async` in front. But that just moves the problem to how to call that, not enough info/context to answer that.

Comment: I tried the public Task<Computer[]> FetchComputers() but I get the same error: Not all code paths return... The GetComputers() method is normal method that returns an Array[] of computer objects, in that method I`m using Thread.Sleep at the beginning to simulate delay that this method will have.

Comment: Not sure what is your expectation here: Either you can have the work done asynchronously and when the method `FetchComputers` returns, you will not have any data to return, or you can run it synchronously and returns the useful data. You can't have both!

Comment: My expectation was to load that array of computers without blocking the UI thread, when it s done it returns an array of computers

Comment: You say "without blocking" and then say "when it is done". Realize that they are opposite requirements

Comment: But when I use Task.Run() this runs in a separated thread right?

Comment: The problem is that if you want the computer fetching to be asynchronous, FetchComputers() will return control to its caller before GetComputers() is done.  It can't return an array to its caller because the array doesn't exist yet.  If this is happening in an event handler you could make all the functions, from the original event handler all the way to FetchComputers() be asynchronous, and use `await` to return control all the way back up to the event loop.  Or you define a real event callback somewhere along the way and use ContinueWith there.

Comment: I did an update, can you please take a look at it and check if it is possible that way? How do I implement the await in this scenario?

Comment: I miss the PMV answer, thank you. I implemented the Task + ContinueWith in the caller with TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() option for ContinueWith and now it s running ok. Thank you